# How can I identify my css to my django project

Tags: python, html, css, django, web

I am new at django and I  could not identify CSS to my django project

Important parts of my project:

**setting.py**

```
"""
Django settings for myshop project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'uhln7d--gk-(i6+py1@f)#su35249@@noydffkj$jd4$l(obj)'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'shop.apps.ShopConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myshop.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myshop.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**view.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Category,Product
from django.views import generic


class ProductListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = "list.html"
    context_object_name='w'
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('list',views.ProductListView.as_view(),name='list')
]
```

**my template(list.html)**

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


        {% for i in w %}

        <p class="p" >{{i.price}}</p>

        <br>
        {{i.name}}<br>

        {% endfor %}


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean by `identify CSS to django` ?

Comment: Do you run into any errors? What does you current code do?

Comment: Please explain precisely what you want to achieve and what's stopping you from achieving it.

Comment: i want to make a list of prices  and names  of product and i rendered it as html but    
I did not succeed to related the css to my html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's important to Django when dealing with static files is where you put them. You have to put all your static files in a `static` folder. In your ... Django then gets all the static folders and treats all of the files in them as if they were in a single folder on the backend. This is why namespacing is so important when it comes to your static files. 
I would recommend the following file structure for all of your django apps.

```
app_directory > static > "a dir with the same name as your app" > css > files go here
```

Replicate the same file structure for all your apps. The folder with the same name as your app isn't strictly a requirement, but it makes sure that there are never any two static files with the same name, which will cause django to fail. 
Now in all your templates where you want to use your static files you must use the `{% load static %}` django tag. Use this tag *before* you put in the  tag.

Comment: i did it
it still wrong 
was my code correct؟
 i mean is it possible the problem  be from code side?not the dir side